# How to create certificates and core files from scratch?

Tags: corda

I want to create certificates for all my nodes automatically to be able this way to scale the number of parties I have when desired. Reading, searching and experimenting, I have concluded what is what I have to do to achieve it. However, I have several questions about it. These are my steps:

1. Create NetworkManager
2. Get/create credentials for NetworkManager (¿How?)
   2.1 You can run `corda.jar generate-rpc-ssl-settings` but it is not likely to be it, because no truststore is created.
3. Copy truststore.jdk form the NetworkManager and save in as network-root-truststore.jdk
4. Deploy nodes (parties and notaries) with network-root-truststore.jdk inside of the certificates folder
5. On these nodes, run `corda.jar initial-registration --network-root-truststore-password=<networkManagerTrustorePassword>`
6. Run on all nodes `corda.jar generate-node-info` to generate NodeInfo files.

*(Point 2)* First of all, ¿how can I create the credentials for NetworkManager? I am not used at all to credentials and .jdk and do not want to install Kotlin on the node just to use the Cordite library.

*(Point 3)* Second, is there a way to get network-root-trustore.jdk on-run from the parties without having to scp the file into them? I am talking about some kind of command like `corda.jar get-network-root-certificate`. If the truststore is a public key (I think so), there should be no problem with that.

*(Point 5)* Is initial-registration enough to create all the main certificates (nodekeystore.jks, sslkeystore.jks, truststore.jks) in the node? Do I have to do something with these nodes?

*(Point 6)* I have not tried it, but I understand that this creates the network-parameters and nodeInfo- files, which are also required by the node to work. Is this correct?

I would also like to know if there is a way to do all of this before starting any node. I'm saying create all the certificates in one point and then distribute them.

A lo of questions but very focused and repetitive. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago I had a PR which shows how to create keystores for Corda nodes. You may use it as a reference:
https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/5101

\Sean

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it only overs the _Point 2_ and there is is specified that I do not want to install Kotlin for it. I am looking for some kind of script like "genCert --arg --arg --arg"

Comment: I see. If you build the project, you can use the resulting jar as follows:

Comment: I see. If you build the project, you can use the resulting jar as follows:
java -jar certgen.jar cert --config cert_def.conf .

Comment: Can you explain me how to build it? I am certainly new to Java.